# If a non-abelian group G of order 12 has a normal 3-subgroup, and a 4-subgroup that is not cyclic, then G contains an element of order 6

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have tried to count the number of elements by their order. Since G is not abelian, there is no element of order 12. There is one element of order 1, 2 elements of order 3, and no elements of order 4 since one 2-sylow not being cyclic implies that non of the 2-sylows are cyclic. Now I only have to show that the number of elements of order 2 is less than 9 but I don't know how to.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $3$ and $K$ be a 2-sylow subgroup. Then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $6$, which is itself cyclic.

Comment: Could you explain why $HK$ is of cardinal 6 and why it's cyclic? Thanks.

Comment: Note that since $H$ and $K$ are 3-sylow and 2-sylow subgroups, their intersection is the identity subgroup. Hence $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} = 3\cdot 2 = 6$. There are only two subgroups of order 6. One of which is cyclic while the other $S_{3}$ is not even abelian leave alone being cyclic. Labor to rule out one.

Comment: But the cardinal of the 2-sylow K is 4.

Comment: Then just take an element of order 2 and it will give you a cyclic group of order 2 and call that K and everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ contains an element of order $2$  say $b$.

$G$ contains an element of order $3$  say $a$ where $\langle a\rangle =\{e,a,a^2\}$
is a normal Sylow-$3$ subgroup of $G$.

Now $bab^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle\implies bab^{-1}=a$
or $bab^{-1}=e$ or $bab^{-1}=a^2$

If $bab^{-1}=a\implies ab=ba\implies o(ab)=o(a)o(b)=6$

If $bab^{-1}=a^2\implies ba=a^2b$. Now consider the subgroup  $\langle a,b\rangle\cong S_3$ which is a subgroup of $G$ .

Also $G$ has $K_4=\{e,a,b,c\}$ the Kleins group as its subgroup .

Then take any $3$ cycle from $S_3$ say $(132)$ and $a\in K_4$. Then $((132),a)$ has order $6$

Comment: But $S_3\times K_4$ is too big to be isomorphic to $G$ no?

Comment: Yes that was wrong;You can even do the problem without it